# Android Game Pad Feasibility

Tags: c#

So, I have seen various posts regarding the use of an android phone as a keyboard and as a game pad. I'm actually working on a project that does just that. As you could imagine, I've hit a massive roadblock when it comes to sending the signal from the phone to the PC via USB.

I decided to use unity as the base of this project. I have a functioning GUI and I have some simple code to basically open the port, push through the Serial.write command, and close the port. I also understand that is code will not do me any good without the PC I'm connected to via USB recognizes the phone as a source of input.

That's where I'm stuck.

I've seen posts that involve explanations of how USB works, the different hex codes mapped to keys, ideas of modifying the kernel, third party programs, and third party devices, but nothing concrete on how to move forward in a video game on my PC by simply tapping the screen on my phone. It should be simple right?

So, I'm asking whether or not this project is worth pursuing for the few months I have left to do it or should I consider pivoting to a project that's a little closer to my pay grade(free)?

Comment: Hey read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as I don't think this question is suitable for SO

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-turn-your-smartphone-into-a-remote-mouse-and-keyboard_id59809) approach.

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not sure if this post is a SO standard question, my train of thought would be to use bluetooth instead of using USB, client-server etc. as they are plagued by problems. While there maybe a certain lag in using bluetooth, programmatically this should be easily achievable. This maybe of interest to you: https://github.com/temach/HIDInterface

Comment: You're most likely correct, and I thank you for your advise. I am reading through the info in the link you gave me.